# Using Django Users for all logged in users, and registering them

Tags: python, django, django-users, python-3.4

I have a site that - other than the signup process - will be only used by logged in users. It's my first Django site, and I'm wondering whether I can use the Django user model (slightly extended) to work with all my users, or should it only be used for administrative users such as myself?

Apologies if this is a stupid question. Additionally, and either way, what's the best way to manage user registrations? It'd be awesome if this were built into Django, but it's not, and I read django-registration is relatively abandoned. Any recommendations welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Django `User` model for all your users (of course, it all depends on your actual scenario, but it sounds like it could work in your case). You can also extend it (e.g. add more fields): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

Is it the best way to manage users? Again, it depends on the scenario, but it would still work for a significant portion of Django projects.

> I read django-registration is relatively abandoned

I haven't used it in a while, but I'd guess it would work with the current Django version. In any case, it's a fairly simple and robust application, so you might be able to tweak it to make it work (you might even decide to commit the changes back to the repo, in the open source spirit).

Comment: I'm going with this answer in my project. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was just talking to an advanced developer friend of mine about this. He said using djangos users is frowned upon and to build it out separately. I don't know much more on this but it's something I will be doing in the future.

Comment: Why on earth would it be frowned upon? Django's user framework is rich and very well bedded in.

Comment: I was told that the django user framework for its admin is really only for true admin purposes. Not to be built out for regular users signing up for a sites functionality. I have no experience with a project in production. But I asked the question to someone with a very successful django/python site with high traffic and that's the answer I was given. I am by no means qualified to have an accurate opinion on this. I am very new with django. But I'm chipping away at it!

Comment: If you find out more, or if your friend could comment directly, that would be amazing. My instinct from using Django for a couple of weeks agrees with your friend's assessment, but obviously it's just a hunch for me.

Comment: Interesting concept, but for every experienced developer who says dont use it, there will be one that says do use it. I'm on the 'do use it' side for sure - I've written many a site using a subclassed User model for authentication, and never had any issue. Re-inventing the wheel springs to mind on this one.

Comment: Hey, I'm the friend @wannabeprogrammer mentioned. We discussed this the other day but I was referring to not allowing public users have access to the admin no matter how tempting. That the admin is for trusted users. I'm all for using the django user model and do so on almost every project. I spoke with him this morning to explain and I just wanted to follow up on here to not cause any confusion for future new users.